# Converting Gregorian date to Hijri

Tags: python, datetime

I want to convert gregorian to hijri after put inputs but i got this error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.datetime)
```

The code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from hijri_converter import convert

war_start = '2011-01-03'

war = datetime.strptime(war_start, '%Y-%m-%d')
war1 = convert.Gregorian(war).to_hijri()

print(war1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the [documentation](https://hijri-converter.readthedocs.io/)

basic usage is to pass in integers

```
convert.Gregorian(1982, 12, 2).to_hijri()
Hijri(1403, 2, 17)
```

You can also construct a Gregorian object from a datetime.date object

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> my_date = date(1982, 12, 2)
>>> convert.Gregorian.fromdate(my_date)
Gregorian(1982, 12, 2)
```

so in your case you could do

```
from datetime import datetime
from hijri_converter import convert

war_start = '2011-01-03'
war = datetime.strptime(war_start, '%Y-%m-%d')
war1 = convert.Gregorian.fromdate(war).to_hijri()
```

Comment: i want to make the date an input from user 
then from code convert it ti hijri

Comment: @MahmoudEl-kousy to use user input - get the user to input the date, convert it to a datetime object and then call the rest, like in the 3rd example above

Comment: If you want to use input from the user, this becomes even easier.

from hijri_converter import convert

year = int(input("Please Enter the 4-digit year: "))
month = int(input("Please Enter the 2-digit month: "))
day = int(input("Please Enter the 2-digit day: "))

print(convert.Gregorian(year, month, day).to_hijri())